# How do I create an NTE|9| Segment in a Group using library version v.2.3.1

Tags: hapi, hl7-v2

I have an NTE segment defined as follows:

NTE|9|\F\400797\F\ENG\F\1\F\THEN TAKE 1 TABLET TWICE A DAY FOR A WEEK.

First I want to be able to create NTE|9 Segment as shown above.  Second, I want to be able to use the NTE|9 in a group.

The group has the following structure:
MSH
PID
ORC
ZPI
NTE|9
ZSP

The segments ORC to ZSP can repeat several times as a group, so I would like to capture them in a group, i.e. ORC to ZSP. The problem is I don't know how to represent the NTE|9 segment by extending AbstractSegment. I am using the HAPI HL7 Library version v2.3.1.